# Convert string array data to arraylist before using it in recycleview adapter

Tags: java, android

I have an api the structure of it like this:

```
{"seasons":[
{
"id":"1",
"titles":"s1episode1;s1episode2;s1episode3"
},
{
"id":"2",
"titles":"s2episode1;s2episode2;s2episode3;s2episode4;s2episode5"
}
]}
```

and so on

and I want data displayed in recycleview app like this:

```
s1episode1
s1episode2
s1episode3
s2episode1
s2episode2
s2episode3
s2episode4
s2episode5
```

so each line represent an item of recycleview

I parse the data and in model class use parcelable:

```
public class Series implements Parcelable {

    private int id;
    private String titles;

    public Series(int id, String titles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeInt(id);
        out.writeString(titles);
    }

    private Series(Parcel in) {
        this.id         = in.readInt();
        this.titles         = in.readString();
    }

    public Series() {
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Series> CREATOR = new Creator<Series>() {
        @Override
        public Series createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Series(in);
        }
        @Override
        public Series[] newArray(int i) {
            return new Series[i];
        }
    };

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitles() {
        return titles;
    }

        public List<String> getEpisodes(){
            String[] titles = getTitles().split(";");

            List<String> titleList = Arrays.asList(titles);

            String titlesArray = null;
            for (String e : titleList) {
                titlesArray += String.valueOf(e);
            }

            return titleList;
        }

}
```

you can see in getEpisodes() I tried to treat the data by convert it from string array to arraylist to prepare it before use it in recycleview

and I create a new collection for RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
class Episode {
    int id;
    String title;

    public Episode(int id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public static List<Episode> createEpisodeList(int id, List<String> titles) {
        List<Episode> episodes = new ArrayList(titles.size());
        for (String title : titles) {
            episodes.add(new Episode(id, title));
        }
        return episodes;
    }
}
```

and this is the code of recycleview adapter:

```
    public class SeriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SeriesAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

        ArrayList<Series> mSeries;
        List<Episode> episodesList = new ArrayList();

        private Context context;
        private SeriesAdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;

public interface SeriesAdapterOnClickHandler {
    void onClick(Series series);
}

    public SeriesAdapter(SeriesAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler) {
        mClickHandler = clickHandler;
    }

    public void setClickListener(SeriesAdapterOnClickHandler callback) {
        mClickHandler = callback;
    }

class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public final TextView title;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        Series series = mSeries.get(adapterPosition);
        mClickHandler.onClick(series);
    }

}

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.series_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);

        RecyclerViewHolder holder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);

        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.title.setText(String.valueOf(mSeries.get(position).getEpisodes()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (null == mSeries)
            return 0;
        else {
            return mSeries.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (null == mSeries)
            return 0;
        else {
            return mSeries.size();
        }
    }

    public void setSeriesData(ArrayList<Series> seriesData) {
        for (Series s : seriesData) {
            episodesList.addAll(Episode.createEpisodeList(s.getEpisodes()));
        }
//        mSeries = seriesData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

but in app the data displayed nothing

so how should I treat the data by convert it from string array to arraylist to prepare it to be used in recycleview and display each episode as single recycle item

like this:

```
    s1episode1
    s1episode2
    s1episode3
    s2episode1
    s2episode2
    s2episode3
    s2episode4
    s2episode5
```

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) you should uncomment mSeries = seriesData in setSeriesData() method in your adapter. Now, getItemCount returns 0, so nothing will be displayed. 2) Have you attached a LayoutManager to your recyclerview? If there is no layout manager, ui drawing is skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new collection for RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
class Episode {
    int id;
    String title;

    public Episode(int id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public static List<Episode> createEpisodeList(int id, List<String> titles) {
        List<Episode> episodes = new ArrayList(titles.size());
        for (String title : titles) {
            episodes.add(new Episode(id, title));
        }
        return episodes;
    }
}
```

and in adapter convert series list to new collection:

```
List<Episode> episodesList = new ArrayList();

void setSeries(List<Series> series) {
    for (Series s : series) {
        episodesList.addAll(Episode.createEpisodeList(s.id, s.getEpisododes()));
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Edited adapter code:

```
public class EpisodeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EpisodeAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_EPISODE = 0; // it's possible to show multiple types recycler

    List<Episode> episodesList = new ArrayList();

    private Context context;
    private AdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;

    public interface AdapterOnClickHandler {
        void onClick(Episode episode);
    }

    public EpisodeAdapter(AdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler) {
        mClickHandler = clickHandler;
    }

    public void setClickListener(AdapterOnClickHandler callback) {
        mClickHandler = callback;
    }

    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public final TextView title;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setData(Episode episode) {
            title.setText(episode.title);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            Episode episode = episodesList.get(adapterPosition);
            mClickHandler.onClick(episode);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.series_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       holder.setData(episodesList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return episodesList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return TYPE_EPISODE;
    }

    public void setSeriesData(ArrayList<Series> seriesData) {
        episodesList.clear();
        for (Series s : seriesData) {
            episodesList.addAll(Episode.createEpisodeList(s.getEpisodes()));
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already tried to create new collection in the way you did but I had problem with deal with it like you did in setSeries so I did what you said but now when I run the app I just got no data displayed
should I leave the holder as it is `holder.title.setText(String.valueOf(mSeries.get(position).getEpisodes()));` while mSeries is the ArrayList<Series>
can I mark your answer as the correct one but complete discussion with you on chat please? @3mpty

Comment: It's better to keep it here - maybe someone else will find out it useful. Edit question and add updated code. ViewHolder should be build around Episode class as it contains data needed by recycler view and it is in proper order in new collection.

Comment: Okay I edit the post again with new codes please see it @3mpty

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused - do you want to display list of episodes or list of series in your recycler?

Comment: I want to display the list of episodes as I said I want the titles of episodes displayed in recycleview why you confused with that @3mpty

Comment: Because you created series adapter but you want  show episode list. This is confusing. Anyway check adapter code that I posted.

Comment: yes I edit the adapter and change it from series to episode and everything work perfect! thanks man you save my day @3mpty

Answer (score 0):

`String.valueOf(list)` (from `holder.title.setText(String.valueOf(mSeries.get(position).getEpisodes()))`) will return such a result, sure. You are just basically calling `arrayListInstance.toString()`. You should override `getItemCount()` method to return the sum (by any way of your preference) of all your series' episode lists sizes, and every bind should return a value FROM the list, not to call `list.toString()` (which is what is going on inside `String.valueOf()`). What I would recommend is to pass a merged list of all series' episodes in the constructor of your recyclerview's implementation.

Comment: I'm already override the getItemCount() and I add it the question now you can see it, and can you explain more please about what you mean with what you recommend @Andrey Ilyunin

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the easy way to do it is by concatenating a line breaker in the method getEpisodes. Something like this (I'm sure there's other, maybe better, ways to do it):

```
public List<String> getEpisodes(){
        String[] titles = getTitles().split(";");

        List<String> titleList = Arrays.asList(titles);

        String titlesArray = null;
        for (String e : titleList) {
            titlesArray += String.valueOf(e) + "\n";
        }

        return titleList;
    }
```